# When symbolic array gets updated, another variable that uses an element of the first array cannot be updated anymore

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math

To simplify my actual problem, let's define the following symbolic expressions.

```
a=sym('a',[1,3]);
b=a(1);
```

If I somehow assign a new thing to `a`, I cannot get `b` to update. What is the proper way of doing this?

Example 1:

```
a=sym('a',[1,3]);
b=a(1);
a=sym([1,2,3]);
b
subs(b)
subs(b,a(1),100)
```

Example 1 Output:

```
b =

a1


ans =

a1


ans =

a1
```

Example 2:

```
a=sym('a',[1,3]);
b=a(1);
a=subs(a,a(1),3);
b
subs(b)
subs(b,a(1),100)
```

Example 2 Output:

```
b =

a1


ans =

a1


ans =

a1
```

Example 3:

```
a=sym('a',[1,3]);
b=a(1);
a(1)=sym(3);
b
subs(b)
subs(b,a(1),100)
```

Example 3 Output:

```
b =

a1


ans =

a1


ans =

a1
```

My actual problem is the following. I have `N` unknowns

```
a=sym('a',[1,N]);
```

and `N` equations.

```
EQN=sym('EQN',[1,N]);
```

`N` is defined according to user input and I don't know what it will be beforehand. I also have other variables that are dependent on `a`.

```
% some code here such as b = [2*a(1),3*a(2),..] etc.
```

Then I solve the equations for the unknowns

```
% some code here to derive EQN(1), EQN(2), ... EQN(N).
SOL=solve(EQN,a);
```

and substitute the solutions to a

```
SOL = struct2cell(SOL);
SOL = [SOL{:}];
a=subs('a',a,SOL);
```

Now I want to get rid of unknowns in `b` but I cannot due to the reason I tried to explain in the beginning.

Comment: What about `subs(b, SOL)`?

Comment: @m7913d I wrote `subs(b,[3,2,1])` to the end of Example 2 assuming that `SOL` came out to be `[3,2,1]` and the output of that line was `[ 3, 2, 1]`. I expected it to be `3` only.

Comment: I mean the `SOL` that is returned by the `solve`  function, which is a structure: `subs(b, solve(EQN, a))`.

Comment: @m7913d I was able to update both `a` and `b` using that syntax. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting `a` instead of assigning a new value to `a1`, `a2` and `a3`. So, you should change the underlying variable instead of `a` itself.

```
a=sym('a',[1,3]);
b = a(1)
a1 = 1; 
subs(b) % returns 1
subs(b, 'a1', a1) % returns 1
subs(a) % [ 1, a2, a3]
```

If you want to use it to substitute the result of a `solve` operation, the best solution is to use [`subs` with the output structure of `solve` as input](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#btqh8qs-1):

```
sol = solve(a == [1 2 3], a);
subs(b, sol) % returns 1
```

Note that you can also manually construct this structure as follows:

```
sol.(char(a(1))) = 1 % sol.a1 = 1;
```

Comment: Yes it seems so. The whole reason I am using `a=sym('a',[1,N])` is to not use for loops which has `eval(['syms a',num2str(i)])` inside. But it seems you cannot get rid of `eval` completely. Note that `N` changes so the subscript that I assign will change. I should be able to change `i` in `ai=1` dynamically inside code.  Is there a way to evaluate the code `a1 = 1` without using `eval(['a',num2str(i),'=1'])`?

Comment: @UtkuTürer I added a method to avoid `eval` at the end of my post.